# Get-DfsrReplication command showing error for Get-ADObject

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, microsoft-distributed-file-system

This is just weird. I have an ec2 instance (for my testing purpose) and what I am trying to achieve is that using powershell install a windows feature (DFS) and configure DFS replication group and the other things. I was able to install this windows feature but configuration fails.

I was trying to use Get-DfsrReplication command.
**Please note that its not Get-DfsReplication, since that too fails that it cant find such a command**

First it failed because that I was not having powershell v4.0. I installed the same. Then it was an issue that I didnt had the DFSR module, I did the same. But again it fails with such a weird error:

```
The term 'Get-ADObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
```

the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What is the connection between Get-ADObject and Get-DfsrReplication commands? or Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: That is one of the active directory cmdlets from the module `ActiveDirectory`. That module might just not be imported maybe? `Get-Module -ListAvailable` might show it under the name column

Comment: @Matt: Yes, such a module is not there. Is there any connection between these two? sorry, I couldn't find any references for the same anywhere..

Comment: @serverstackqns Dfsr relies on AD, and needs to be able to retrieve the DFS replication group configuration objects from AD, hence the error

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: That was unknown to me. Is there any other dependencies for using DFS through powershell..?

Comment: No, Install the PowerShell Module for Active Directory from Server Manager and you should be good to go